# phpinfo reads php5.5 instead of php5.6

Tags: php, apache, osx-yosemite

I have php5.6 on yosemite via brew running on Apache, but yet my phpinfo file shows php5.5

I have updated the `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file load module to:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

I have restarted apache. I have restarted the terminal after adding both:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php56/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php56)/bin:$PATH"
```

which php returns

```
/usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php
```

I have restarted the entire computer and when running a phpinfo file returns

```
PHP Version 5.5.20
```

Comment: Are you sure you're modifying the right php.ini? There is one for the webserver and one for the command line interface(CLI).

Comment: The folder is named php56 but did you actually install php5.6?

Comment: I ran brew install php56 and I also edited /etc/php.ini to include_path="/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.9/bin/php"

Comment: Try changing the order of the path it happened to me before PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH” should be before /usr/sbin

Comment: Do you mean:
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php56)/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php56/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"